# Running HtmlUnit with Jython - issue with startup on command line

Tags: java, python, jython, htmlunit

I tried to run HtmlUnit with Jython following this tutorial:

http://blog.databigbang.com/web-scraping-ajax-and-javascript-sites/

but it does not work for me. I am unable to import the *com.gargoylesoftvare* packages, there are only some HTML files in HtmlUnit folder, which I need to import somehow?

The tutorial says to run python script like this:

```
/opt/jython/jython -J-classpath "htmlunit-2.8/lib/*" gartner.py
```

and I try to run:

```
java -jar /Users/adam/jython/jython.jar -J-classpath "htmlunit-2.8/lib/*" gartner.py
```

My problem is I am getting an "Unknown option: J-classpath". But there is not even word about -J-classpath parameter on Jython.org. I would be VERY glad for any advice. I am running jython standalone v. 2.5.2 on Snow Leopard

Comment: Hi have you been able to run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire command line is being processed by the `java` command (as it should), and *-J-classpath* is indeed not a valid command line option for `java`. You should really try to follow the exact steps of the tutorial, because you are missing several important steps (and kind of making up your own steps).

Comment: I am little bit confused. How Can I run Jython without Java then?

Comment: Excellent. Good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: what did you do to fix the problem? -J-classpath is not a valid parameter for jython.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run a Jython script as: jython myscript.py if the script appends the full url to the python path using sys.path.append of the jars that a script will require to run.

Here is a current script I'm working on.

```
#!/opt/jython/jython
'''
Created on Dec 7, 2011
@author: chris
'''
import sys, os
from time import sleep

jarpath = '/usr/share/java/htmlunit/' #path the jar files to import
jars = ['apache-mime4j-0.6.jar','commons-codec-1.4.jar',
    'commons-collections-3.2.1.jar','commons-io-1.4.jar',
    'commons-lang-2.4.jar','commons-logging-1.1.1.jar',
    'cssparser-0.9.5.jar','htmlunit-2.8.jar',
    'htmlunit-core-js-2.8.jar','httpclient-4.0.1.jar',
    'httpcore-4.0.1.jar','httpmime-4.0.1.jar',
    'nekohtml-1.9.14.jar','sac-1.3.jar',
    'serializer-2.7.1.jar','xalan-2.7.1.jar',
    'xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar','xml-apis-1.3.04.jar'] #a list of jars

def loadjars(): #appends jars to jython path
    for jar in jars:
        print(jarpath+jar+'\n')
        container = jarpath+jar
        sys.path.append(container)

loadjars()

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient as WebClient
webclient = WebClient()   

def gotopage():
    print('hello, I will visit Google')
    url = 'http://google.com'
    page = webclient.getPage(url)
    print(page)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gotopage()
```

Comment: doesn't work! Using htmlunit-2.16 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/htmlunit/2.16/)

Comment: @Napstar Here is an updated version that downloads the dependencies itself: https://github.com/ysangkok/buddyledger-test/blob/master/integration-test.py It currently only depends on Bash, Curl and Java. Jython, Ivy and HtmlUnit are automatically downloaded. Ignore the Django stuff

Answer (score 0):

I have met such error before, and do these steps i solve it successfully.

1. download jython and run `java -jar python-installer-xxx.jar`to install jython, then you can put `jython/bin` folder to your system path, run `jython` in command line to ensure it's ok.
2. download htmlunit jar files in sourceforge and you need to specific its location.
3. write your .py file and run

   `jython -J-classpath "/Users/crabime/Development Folder/htmlunit-2.23/lib/*" /Users/crabime/PycharmProjects/scrapimage/crabime/gartner.py`

everything will ok,if you still miss module not found, maybe you should check your input command type error.