# Running HtmlUnit with Jython

Tags: jython, htmlunit, importerror

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758469/running-htmlunit-with-jython-issue-with-startup-on-command-line) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774498/instantiating-a-webclient-object-in-jython-giving-strange-results)

I am running windows 7(x64) and following the example on this page:
http://blog.databigbang.com/web-scraping-ajax-and-javascript-sites/

I get a similar error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\gartner.py", line 24, in 
        import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient as WebClient
    ImportError: No module named gargoylesoftware
```

Running the script as (with the latest htmlunit-2.9):

```
>> jython -J-classpath "htmlunit-2.9/lib/*" gartner.py
```

I have also attempted second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758469/running-htmlunit-with-jython-issue-with-startup-on-command-line) to no avail.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

**Edit1:**
I added "htmlunit-2.9/lib/" to my classpath through the system environment variables.

```
>> jython gartner.py
```

Same error as above.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I extracted all the jar files via `ls *.jar | xargs -i jar xf {}` and then threw them in `/usr/share/jython/Lib`. That resolved the import error, but I'm getting a new one now: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/CredentialsProvider`